# How to smooth out coarse geometry?

Tags: modeling, geometry, smooth, sapling-addon

I have some input geometry that looks like this:

[image]

I wanted to try to smooth it out so I first did a couple fo steps of the smooth modifier, followed by2 catmull-clark subdivisions:

[image]

Since the input geometry was already kinda iffy I am not getting a perfectly smooth result, I was wondering if people knew of something I could do to fix this?

Comment: Does right-click > Shade Smooth help?

Comment: I am doing this for geometry applications, so hiding the uglies with better shading is not a solution. To be clear, my issue is not that the quads are visible, but that there are lots of large "bumps" on the furcation. They look like small tumors.

Comment: Ok. It's always best to give as much information in your question as possible to avoid spurious answers like mine.